# Cannot mock "window" with jasmine/karma and typescpript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I am trying to mock "window" object in the jasmine/karma unit tests.
I've tried almost all solutions and anything didn't help me.

1. The simpliest:

```
const mockWindow: any = () => {
            return {
                navigator: {
                    userAgent: "Edge"
                }
            };
        };

//in some test
window = mockWindow();
```

> Error: TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. (line25) "Jasmine"

2. Another one:

```
class MockWindow {
        public navigator =  { userAgent: "Edge" };
    }

//in some test
window = new MockWindow() as any;
```

> Error: TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. (line25) "Jasmine"

3. Using defineProperty:

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, "userAgent", {
                value: () => "Edge",
                configurable: true,
                writable: true
            });
```

As you can see, I've also tried this solution with attributes like "configurable" and "writable".

> Error: TypeError: Attempting to configurable attribute of unconfigurable property. (line 25) "Jasmine"

4. Using jasmine mock:

```
spyOn<any>(window, "navigator").and.returnValue({ userAgent: "Edge" });
```

It runs without errors but window isn't mocked.
5. Tricky one:

```
window.navigator['__defineGetter__']('userAgent', function(){
    return 'Edge';
  });
```

> Error: TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"**defineGetter**"' >can't be used to index type 'Navigator'.
>    Property '**defineGetter**' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.

I'm sure some solution must exist. I remember doing the same mock in another project and everything worked good. Maybe I have to add some configuration properties in the karma/jasmine/typescript configs.

Please help!)

Answer (score 0):

The window object contains most of the environment, so nuking it would not be a great idea.
I think that what you are actually trying to do is overwrite the browser userAgent string.

If you run:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.navigator, 'userAgent');
// {"writable":false,"enumerable":false,"configurable":false}
```

You see that the property is not configurable or writable. This is why it fails to overwrite it.

However, you can try:

```
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () { return 'Edge'; });
```

Use it with caution, as it is deprecated.
[Object.prototype.**defineGetter**()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__)

As of February 2020 you can change the reported userAgent string in [Chrome DevTools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EiPb1opH3g&t=128s).